# Didn't get a response from the Apple Software Update Center? / Can't load data from the Apple Software Update server

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, macos

The past few days I 've been encountering this problem. When I search for updates through the Mac App Store, there comes a pop - up window.
Either this :
[image]

or this:

[image]

Ι also "cleared cookies" and "resetted the application" through the Debug menu, but these options didn't seem to offer any help.

Comment: The Mac App Store has been having issue the least few days, from what I hear.  Not sure if it has been resolved, but may want to stay patient or download the updates manually from apple.com/downloads.

Comment: @willWorkForCookies Ok, thank you! I thought I was the only one having this issue, since there were no enough results referring to the specific problem, when I googled it.